# Can ack read patterns from a file?

Tags: ack

`grep` can look for a list of patterns written in a file with `grep -f patterns_file search_files`

Can `ack` read a list of patterns from a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it can't, after looking at the [features comparison](https://beyondgrep.com/feature-comparison/)

`grep`, `git-grep` and `rg` can do it.